# Get fps data of Android app using adb failed when android version is 7.0

Tags: android, adb, frame-rate

I use adb command `adb shell dumpsys SurfaceFlinger --latency SurfaceView` to get the current view's fps data and everything works fine when Android version is lower than 7.0.
However, in Android 7.0, this command doesn't work. It only gives me output like:

> 16666666

and nothing else. I tried replace `SurfaceView` with specific window name and nothing changed.

Is there a valid way to get android fps via adb command?
I know about `Tiny Dancer` but I prefer adb command. Thanks.

I tried `adb shell dumpsys gfxinfo <PKG_NAME> framestats` and the result kept the same. :(.

Comment: you might want to take a look at [systrace](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/systrace-commandline.html), it's a very fancy tool

Comment: @lelloman, thanks for your advice. I tried systrace and it doesn't seem to be the best option for my application which needs to monitor the fps status during app running while systrace dumping costs too much time.